# MatPlotLib printing out graphs on the same line next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am making a program that reads in multiple two dimensional lists and plots them as step graph functions. I want to print out each set of graphs side by side like so (I made the graphs different colors just to differentiate the two):

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2GdG.png)

However my code right now makes these two sets overlap each other instead, like so:

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUGSF.png)

I believe it might have something to do with my "t" variable in plotPoints but I am not sure what I need to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# supress warning message
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
# extension libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plotPoints(bits, color):
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        data = np.repeat(bits[i], 2)
        t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data))

        plt.step(t, data + i * 3, linewidth=1.5, where='post', color=color)


        # Labels the graphs with binary sequence
        for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits[i]):
            plt.text(tbit + 0.3, 0.1 + i * 3, str(bit), fontsize=6, color=color)


def main():

    plt.ylim([-1, 32])

    set1 = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
    set2 = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]


    plotPoints(set1, 'g')
    plotPoints(set2, 'b')


    # removes the built in graph axes and prints line every interation
    plt.gca().axis('off')
    plt.ylim([-1, 10])


    plt.show()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some offset to `t`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plotPoints(bits, color, offset=0):
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        data = np.repeat(bits[i], 2)
        t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data)) + offset

        plt.step(t, data + i * 3, linewidth=1.5, where='post', color=color)


        # Labels the graphs with binary sequence
        for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits[i]):
            plt.text(tbit + 0.3 +offset, 0.1 + i * 3, str(bit), fontsize=6, color=color)


def main():

    set1 = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
    set2 = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]


    plotPoints(set1, 'g')
    plotPoints(set2, 'b', offset=len(set1[0]))


    # removes the built in graph axes and prints line every interation
    plt.gca().axis('off')
    plt.ylim([-1, 10])


    plt.show()

main()
```

[image]